# Given an XML document, how can you list all attributes and elements obeying the order of the xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Given the following XML:

```
<Student number=2020 >
<Subject>Comp<Subject>
<Credintials>
<Password>....</Password>
</Credintials>
<PersonalDetails age=30 height=2/>
</Student>
```

I want to get:

```
Student
@number
Subject
Credintials
Password
PersonalDetails
@age
@height
```

in this order.

So basically if I Parse this XDocument, I get elements separately and attributes separately which disobeys the xml hierarchy.

```
   var attributes = xDocument.Descendants().Attributes();
   var elements = xDocument.Descendants().Elements();
```

I am looping this separately hence i am getting attributes first and then elements

Is there any way to list using the above order ?

Comment: Your request is fine for elements, but be aware that treating XML attributes as having an order is contrary to the XML recommendation and [***should be avoided***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19718720/290085).

Comment: Any chance you'd expand the question and tell us _why_ you want to do this? It may be there's a better way to achieve what you want. If it's just for the sheer intellectual pig iron of it then that's a reason too.

Comment: Forgo LINQ to XML and just use `XmlReader` to read the XML from beginning to end in one pass.

Comment: Did you mean something like this:using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
           while(reader.Read())
           {
               if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
               {
                  List.Add(XmlNodeType.Attribute);
               }
               if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
               {
                  list.Add(XmlNodeType.Element);
               }
           }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just recursively return the element name, attribute names, and child elements:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetNodes(XElement xe)
{
   yield return xe.Name.ToString();
   foreach(XAttribute xa in xe.Attributes())
      yield return ("@"+xa.Name);
   foreach(XElement xee in xe.Elements())
      foreach(var s in GetNodes(xee))
          yield return s;

}
```

usage:

```
string xml = @"<Student number='2020'>
    <Subject>Comp</Subject>
    <Credintials>
    <Password>....</Password>
    </Credintials>
    <PersonalDetails age='30' height='2'/>
    </Student>";

XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = GetNodes(x.Root);
```

result:

```
IEnumerable<String> (8 items)
------------------------------ 
Student 
@number 
Subject 
Credintials 
Password 
PersonalDetails 
@age 
@height
```

Comment: I am now trying to get attributes & elements which have InnerText only using this solution, which yields the following list ie, @number,Subject,Password,@age,@height only.. That's the actual list i want.

Comment: @Tee should be a fairly simple `if` statement in the innermost `foreach`.  If you can't figure it out ask another question.