# How to get attribute count before specific attribute?

Tags: xslt, xpath-1.0

I'm using XPath1.0

XML:

```
<A a="2" b="2" c="2" d="2" e="2"/>
```

Q: How many attributes before attribute `d`

A: There are 3 attributes(`a`,`b`,`c`) before attribute `d`

If `a`~`e` are not attributes but elements, I can do this:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(../A/*[text()='d']/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

But now `a`~`e` are attributes, how can I do the same between `<xsl:template match="/">` and `</xsl:template>`

Comment: Attributes are considered "unordered" in XML (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746224/in-xml-is-the-attribute-order-important)

Comment: Duplicate of [***XSLT to order attributes***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718597/xslt-to-order-attributes)